# Кракозябры при отображении дат в PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql-developer

Как исправить кракозябры именно при отображении дат? Текст и числа отображаются вполне корректно. При этом Toad и PyCharm отображают даты также корректно, проблема именно в PL/SQL Developer. Результаты следующего запроса также совпадают в разных средах:

```
select a.parameter, a.value from nls_session_parameters a;
```

Пример не корректного отображения дат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не оно https://stackoverflow.com/a/8134646/407561?

Comment: @NMD К сожалению, нет. Видел тот тикет - не помогло. Там у парня нормально всё отображается (без кракозябр) просто не в том формате (без времени). То есть 15-NOV-11 вместо 15-NOV-11 22/12/12